# Animación CSS no funciona

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer una pequeña animación en uno de los iconos, pero no me sale cómo hacerlo... Este es el código que tengo

```css
#pruebamov2 {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateY(10deg);
  animation: pruebamov2 0.5s 2;
  perspective: 100px;
}

@keyframes pruebamov2 {
  50% {perspective: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
   <p>
   <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue" id="pruebamov2">business_center</i>
   Hola
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Se supone que debería rotar 10º, y volver a 0, y volver a repetirlo una vez más. Todo eso en 0.5 segundos, pero no hace nada.

No tengo ni idea de lo que me falta, o lo que he hecho mal. Tengo otra animación que esa funciona perfectamente.

¿Qué podría ser? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que rote `10` grados cambia en el `@keyframes` `perspective: 100px;` por `transform: rotate(10deg);`. Supongo que esto era de tu otra animación y no lo has modificado :)

Comment: ¡Era eso! Estaba tocando ya tantas cosas que se me debió haber colado por algún lado y no me di cuenta. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dijo @x3k against SE behavior en los comentarios, era simplemente cambiar

```
@keyframes pruebamov2 {
  50% {perspective: 100px;}
}
```

por

```
@keyframes pruebamov2 {
transform: rotate(10deg);
```

Y quedaría de la forma deseada:

```css
#pruebamov2 {
  position: relative;
  transform: rotateY(10deg);
  animation: pruebamov2 0.5s 2;
  perspective: 100px;
}

@keyframes pruebamov2 {
  50% { transform: rotate(10deg); }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
   <p>
   <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue" id="pruebamov2">business_center</i>
   Hola
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar, si ibas a usar la perspectiva para que se viera por debajo te recomiendo esto:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

```css
#pruebamov2 {
  position: relative;
  animation: pruebamov2 1s 2;
  perspective: 100px;
}

@keyframes pruebamov2 {
 from {
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
 }
  to {
   transform: rotateY(100deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
   <p>
   <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color: DarkSlateBlue" id="pruebamov2">business_center</i>
   Hola
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```